# Pros and Cons of Reviews microdata markup

Tags: microdata, schema.org, rich-snippets

using review microdata is there a way to markup individual "Pros" and "Cons" outside of the review description? using schema.org or microformats
no info on http://schema.org/Review

useful where there are lists of pros and cons on top of the long review description.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: [example](http://www.ezcontactsusa.com/Acuvue-contact-lenses/acuvue-oasys.html#pettabs_reviews)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, schema.org’s [`http://schema.org/Review`](http://schema.org/Review) doesn’t define such properties.

The actual review is given by the [`reviewBody` property](http://schema.org/reviewBody), which would include both, pros and cons.